# Item automatically indenting to the left rather than the right?

Tags: indentation, itemize

When trying to use itemize, I was hoping it would give me the natural indent to the right and indent everything that I write within it. Instead its doing the opposite and indenting to the left.  This has never happened to me before.  Anyone know what's going on?

Sample:

```
\noindent
\texit{Case 1} Stuff to write:
\begin{itemize}
    \item[\textit{Case 1.1}] Stuff about stuff
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: We would need to see more of the document. Add at least the documentclass you are using and make the code example compilable.

Comment: @gorzardfu Can you try to explain more, possibly with a visual illustration?

Comment: Have you tried using the `paralist` (or `enumitem`) package ?  They offer more flexible `itemize` lists.

Comment: Thanks everyone for willing to help, but @Werner answered my problem below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default alignment for `\item`s inside an `enumerate` an `itemize` is right. That means longer-than-usual `\item`s tend to be pushed into the left margin. Since you're using a fixed (unenumerated) label, you might as well use a `description` environment which naturally left-aligned its `\item`s with the left margin:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum,showframe}% For this example

\begin{document}

\noindent
\textit{Case 1} This is an \verb|itemize| environment:
\begin{itemize}[font=\normalfont\itshape]
  \item[Case 1.1] \lipsum[1]
\end{itemize}

\noindent
\textit{Case 1} This is a \verb|description| environment:
\begin{description}[font=\normalfont\itshape]
  \item[Case 1.1] \lipsum[1]
\end{description}

\end{document}
```